# Arabic / Hebrew text and memory usage

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, memory-management, arabic, hebrew

I'm working on a fairly basic website that uses quite a bit of Arabic and Hebrew.  It's built with Bootstrap 3 and Wordpress as a CMS, and it doesn't have a lot going on (i.e. 20 pages, almost zero plugins). When I do some performance monitoring on it I'm getting out of control memory usage numbers, with load averages in the 40s and frequent notifications that I'm exceeding Wordpress' memory limit. Does anyone have any idea why this would be?  Is there something about Arabic / Hebrew that can cause this to happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing too special about `herbrew / arabic` . It is just wordpress, and probably `plugins` and the `theme`you have .

The only thing that can take a bit more memory is the usage of `text domains` and translations plugins, but that will be the same for each language combo..

You probably have a lot of queries going on, but it is hard to say without any details ..

anyhow, for a quick fix try :

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); // or 96..
```

Add that to `wp-config`.

There is also `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` - but according to codex it is only for the admin area..

if that is no help ( and only IF ), add

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

to your `.htaccess`.